# Simplifying euler exponent?

Tags: exponentiation

How would I go about simplifying and finding the exact value for this question:

$e^{6\ln(4)}$

I know that $e ^{\ln x} = x$ but how does the $6$ affect this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a^{bc} = \left(a^c\right)^b$$

If $a=e$ and $c=\ln(4)$, then $a^c = 4$. You should be able to do the rest yourself.

Answer (score 0):

$6 \ln 4 = \ln (4^6)$

So, $e^{6 \ln 4} = e^{\ln (4^6)}$.